# Python Bokeh table columns and headers don't line up

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, bokeh

I am trying to display a table in a jupyter notebook using python and the visualization library [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/index.html). I use the following code to display my table in an jupyter notebook where **result** is a dataframe:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(result)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="ts", title="Timestamp"),
        TableColumn(field="bid_qty", title="Bid Quantity"),
        TableColumn(field="bid_prc", title="Bid Price"),
        TableColumn(field="ask_prc", title="Ask Price"),
        TableColumn(field="ask_qty", title="Ask Quantity"),
    ]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, fit_columns=True, width=1300, height=800)
show(widgetbox([data_table], sizing_mode = 'scale_both'))
```

Previously I was using vform although this now seems to be depreciated and no longer works as expected either. This occurred after my jupyter notebook version was updated. Regardless of what I set the width my column headers don't line up and have a weird overlap with the table:

[image]

This did not happen before, I was able to get a nice table where everything lined up. Even if I adjust the headers they still wont line up. This does not happen when I save the table as an html file instead of calling show() directly in the Jupyter notebook. What do I need to change? Is there a better way to do this?

**Full Example**

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import TableColumn, DataTable
import pandas as pd

output_notebook()

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 
 'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="one", title="One"),
    TableColumn(field="two", title=" Two"),
]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, 
    fit_columns=True, width=800, height=800)
show(widgetbox([data_table], sizing_mode = 'scale_both'))
```

This is running on a system with the following versions:

- Jupyter 4.2.0
- Python 2.7.12 (Anaconda 2.3.0 64 bit)
- Bokeh 0.12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css styling of Bokeh widgets for Jupyter notebooks is in http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.css, where `height:16px` for elements `.bk-root .bk-slick-header-column.bk-ui-state-default` is hardcoded. So it cannot be changed without changing the css.

It can be styled adhoc by `HTML` function

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
.bk-root .bk-slick-header-column.bk-ui-state-default {
height: 25px!important;
}
</style>
""")
```

For the persistent change css can be added to `custom` directory in Jupyter config. You can figure out where it is by calling

```
jupyter --config-dir
```

By default it is `~/.jupyter`
The new css need to be in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` then.

Before[image]

After[image]

Comment: what about the width not lining up?

Comment: It is more difficult to fix, because widths of header and rows are set differently in css conditions. It is possible to use

`.bk-root .bk-slick-header-column.bk-ui-state-default:first-child {
width: 40px!important;
}`

but only first column would be aligned